# Axiomatisability of the class of finite groups

Tags: finite-groups, model-theory, axioms

I'm trying to prove that the class of all finite groups is not finitely axiomatizable. I was trying to do this in the same way one proves that the class of finite sets is not axiomatizable, i.e.

Let $\phi_n=\forall x_1\ldots\forall x_n\left[\bigwedge\limits_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\neg(x_i=x_j)\wedge\forall x_{n+1}\bigvee\limits_{1\leq i\leq n} x_{n+1}=x_i\right]$

Then we want to express $\phi_1\vee\phi_2\vee\ldots$

But there is no formula $\psi$ such that $(V)\models\psi\iff V$ is finite. Since: Assume there is a $\psi$. Find the quantifier rank $n$ of $\psi$. Then $(\{0,\ldots,n-1\})\equiv_n(\{0,\ldots,n\})$ but not $(\{0,\ldots,n-1\})\equiv_{n+1}(\{0,\ldots,n\})$ and therefore, for all $i\geq n$:

if $(\{0,\ldots,i\})\models\psi$ then $(\mathbb{N})\models\psi$.

But can this be done for finite groups as well, since we are dealing with multiplication?

Comment: Finitely axiomatizable? It is not even an elementary class!

Comment: And how can I see it's not an elementary class?

Comment: Use compactness theorem. Assume that $T$ is a set of axioms for the class of all finite groups, add constants $\{c_0,c_1,c_2,\ldots\}$ to language, and consider theory $T'= T\cup\{c_i\neq c_j\mid i\neq j\}$. Show that it is finitely satisfiable, hence by compactness satisfiable. Since a model of $T'$ is not finite, you'll reach a contradiction.

Comment: Or you can use ultraproducts. $\psi$ must hold in any ultraproduct of the groups $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ $n = 1, 2, \ldots$, but that ultraproduct is not finite.

Comment: Indeed @RobArthan, that's exactly what I have done myself after posting this question

Comment: Here is another argument using compactness: Assume $T$ is a set of axioms for the class of finite groups. Let $c$ be a new constant and set $T'=T\cup\{c \neq e, c^2\neq e, c^3 \neq e,...\}$ (where $e$ is the identity element). Any finite subset of $T'$ has a model since all the $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ are models of $T$. Therefore, $T'$ has model containing an element with infinte order but this model cannot be finite.